# Changing brightness of the device using BLE in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying to changing the brightness of the device but status we are getting as a success .
But device brightness is not responding.

Can any one help on the issue

```
 public void sendCommands(BluetoothGatt gatt) throws JSONException {

        if (bluetoothGatt != null) {

            List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = bluetoothGatt.getServices();

            if (2 == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) // BLE Is connected after provision as ghatt is connected.
            {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   
                    return;
                }
                gatt.requestMtu(512);

                for (int i = 0; i < gattServices.size(); i++) {
                    String serviceUUID = gattServices.get(i).getUuid().toString();
                    if (serviceUUID.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_GUID)) {
                        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattServices.get(i).getCharacteristics();
                        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                                gattCharacteristics) {
                            final String uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                            if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(TX_CHAR_GUID)) {
                                 String jsonString = "{'i': 1, 'v': 1, 't': 8, 's': 'dbri', 'n': 70}";
                                 
                                byte[] payload = jsonString.getBytes();
                                gattCharacteristic.setValue(payload+"\r\n");
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // TODO: Consider calling
                                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                                    return;
                                }
                                gatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                            }
                        }
               }
         }
    }
```

expecting to change the brightness of the device

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. After studying your [incomplete source code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example, I think it is most likely that your application simply lacks the necessary rights to fulfil its function, or is there a good reason why you commented out the most important part and replaced it with a return?

Comment: You will need to share a lot more infomration. What device are you trying to control over bluetooth? Can you provide the spec you are trying to follow? 

Without this info it will be impossible to help.

Comment: trying to control portable battery via bluetooth .In the device setting we have an option called brightness ,that brightness want to change based on the code for that we are passing payload to the device and for getting the characterics in bytes format.