# Android BLE: knowing MTU on the GattServer side but device not responding

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have implemented BLE communications on Android. I'm negotiating the MTU on the client side using requestMtu. This works well, as the client gets the MTU change on onMtuChanged. However, I still don't have the means to know the MTU on the server side, only the client.

I am implemented this feature to control brightness of the device ,when we are trying to call the method the device is not responding .

But issue with the requestmtu if I completeley removed requestmtu able to see the logs,apart from this I am not able to see any logs.

Can any one help me with the issue

```
public static final String SERVICE_GUID = "6d1b33f8-0000-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003";
 public static final String TX_CHAR_GUID = "6d1b33f8-0014-11eb-a8b3-0242ac130003";
 public void sendCommands(BluetoothGatt gatt) throws JSONException {

    if (bluetoothGatt != null) {

        List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = bluetoothGatt.getServices();

        if (2 == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) // BLE Is connected after provision as ghatt is connected.
        {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    gatt.requestMtu(512);
                }
            }, 20000);

            for (int i = 0; i < gattServices.size(); i++) {
                String serviceUUID = gattServices.get(i).getUuid().toString();
                if (serviceUUID.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_GUID)) {
                    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> gattCharacteristics = gattServices.get(i).getCharacteristics();
                    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic :
                            gattCharacteristics) {
                        final String uuid = gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString();
                        if (uuid.equalsIgnoreCase(TX_CHAR_GUID)) {
                            String jsonString = "{\"i\":1,\"v\":1,\"t\":8,\"s\":\"dbri\",\"n\":50}";
                            byte[] payload = jsonString.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
                            gattCharacteristic.setValue(payload);
                            /*System.out.println("Length:"+payload.length);

                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                                String byte_one=obj.getString("i");
                                System.out.println("byte_one:"+byte_one);
                                byte[] payload1 = byte_one.getBytes();

                            } catch (Throwable t) {
                               // Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + obj + "\"");
                            }*/
                            gatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On change Mtu used below ovveride method:

```
 @Override
        public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status) {
            super.onMtuChanged(gatt, mtu, status);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            gatt.requestMtu(mtu);
            Log.i(TAG, "New MTU: " + mtu + " , Status: " + status + " , Succeed: " + (status == gatt.GATT_SUCCESS));
        }
```

Comment: Simply removing the permissions part of your code will not solve your problem.
You need to declare and request the necessary permissions and the user of your application needs to grant them to your application. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76859739/changing-brightness-of-the-device-using-ble-in-android

Comment: What error message do you get? You only have posted the sending code, but to the receiving code, so are you sure you would notice the response if there is any?

Comment: I am not getting any error ,when I am try to send the mtu to 512 and device is not responsing

Comment: Do you properly make sure you don't send any GATT requests while another is already pending. For example, you may not send a write request while you are still waiting for an mtu update request to complete.

Comment: @Emil updated my code please have a look once

Comment: The `onMtuChanged` callback will deliver the response for your `requestMtu` request. You should not call `requestMtu` again, since that will result in a forever "loop".